# Intern and efficient memory use of string in python

Tags: python

How Python does sys.intern() works.

```
>>> x = '123'
>>> y = '12'
>>> y = y+'3'
# assigned new location to save it. logical as y calculated at run time.
>>> x is y
False
>>> x == y
True
# logical it is now pointing to predefined '123'.
>>> intern(y) is x
True
```

My question is

```
# adding white space in string intern is not working.
>>> x = '123 4'
>>> intern('123 4') is x
False
>>> intern('123 4') is intern(x)
True
```

Why need to use intern on x?

Second question.

```
>>> id('123 4')== id('123 4')
True
# also returns true
>>> x = '123 4'; y ='123 4'; id(x) == id(y)
True
```

## But this same thing returns false.

```
>>> x = '123 4'
>>> y = '123 4'
>>> id(x) == id(y)
False
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: >>> intern('123 4') is intern(x)
True
Why i have to use intern on both?

Comment: Because `intern` can only affect the string that was given to it. It can ensure that any *future* attempt to make a string that looks like `'123 4'` is pulled out of the pool, but that doesn't affect *other existing* string objects that happen to be equal. To make that work, it would have to search for every object in the program.

Comment: >>> x = '123'   
>>> intern('123') is x    
Returns True.
No needed to do intern here? 
Please suggest some answer on my second question asked above.